# Is there any way to get props in React class other than in render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can get all props passed in React class in its `render` method. 
But if I try to do the same in `componentDidMount()` or even in `constructor()` - no luck.

When debugging I can see props in

```
componentDidMount(){
  const { users } = this.props <-props are already there   
  console.log('users from did mount', users); <-- undefined here
}
```

and nothing appears in `users` variable.

When the **same** code fires in `render()` method -- all is working fine.

upd: full class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { firebaseDB, functions } from '../firebase'
import map from 'lodash/map'

export default class Users extends Component {

state = {
  users: []
}


componentDidMount(){
  const { users } = this.props 
  console.log('users from did mount', users); // undefined here
  // here I'd like to some work with those props   
}

handleUser = user => () => {
// console.log('user to handle:',user); //is here
... handling user data 
}

render() {
  const { users } = this.props //ok
  console.log('users from render', users);//see it

  return (
  <div className="container">

    {users ? 
      <div>
      <h4 className="text-primary">Users List</h4>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">email</th>
            <th scope="col">Something</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
          map(users, (user, key) => (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td>{user.displayName}</td>
              <td>{user.email}</td>

              <td><button 
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={this.handleUser(user)}
              >ok</button></td>

            </tr>  
          ))
        }

        </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>    
      :
      "There are no users yet "
    } 
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

users are firebase object, comes from parent above

```
{ id1: {...}, id2: {...} }
```

Comment: Post your full class

Comment: This doesn't sound right, could you add more code? As is this should work.

Comment: @ZekeDroid - post updated

Comment: In `constructor()`, `props` are received as a parameter: `constructor(props)`

Comment: @d2048 You probably receive users after mount. You should log `this.props` in `componentWillUpdate` to see if that's true.

Comment: there's something confusing: you are defining `users` in `state`, but you never write to `state`. where are from users are supposed to come into `props`? is it result of asynchronous action in parent component?

Comment: regarding @FK82's comment: `componentWillUpdate` is deprecated in modern versions of react. you should use `componentDidUpdate` if you want to watch changes in a prop

Comment: @Max Komarychev - those `users` are coming in props from upper parent. I am defining them in `render` method, they are working there to show users table. I want extend those `users` coming with some data and push them in state to work with later.

Comment: @d2048 is it possible to see parent class as well and how these two are used together? are users coming from async operation or no?

Comment: @MaxKomarychev I was just suggesting this for debugging.

Comment: @FK82 - did a research )) From console in order of arrearance 1) users from will mount [], 2) users from render [], 3) users from did mount [] 4) users from will update [], 5) users from render {-LHtZXlkVQRjVbrsiNgV: {…}, -LHtwWCQobSClsUffXRj: {…}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` method in case if `users` prop is coming from async

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.props.users !== nextProps.users){
    console.log('should appear here', nextProps.users);
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, `componentDidUpdate` should be used instead. but this doesn't seem to be a case here

Comment: Ooh yes you're right @MaxKomarychev, Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work, it just means there is a better replacement for it, and yes we should use `componentDidUpdate` in React 17 it's better thanks for letting me know.

Comment: you can also use shouldComponentUpdate() which will allow you to stop it from rerendering by returning false

Comment: @d2048 In some cases we should use `componentWillReceiveProps` if the props are receiving from async that's mean it takes a parts of second after the component is mounted So the `componentDidMount` will not regonaize that.

Comment: @Liam - when debugging (using vscode ) I see those props alive in `componentDidMount` -> `const { users } = this.props` , but `{users}` here appears empty. Do U know why?

Comment: @nathanhayfield I don't think it's good to use `shouldComponentUpdate` because he will not be able to use the props in the component if the prop received new data

Comment: @Liam yes it depends what you want to do with the props

Comment: @d2048 this is because `users` props it doesn't exist in the next step of the `this.props` it takes parts of a second to be ready, does `users` prop is coming from async?